# Inverse-Fourier transform of a function after non-linear frequency modulation

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

Suppose $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{g}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ too. So $\tilde{g}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi \xi^2}\hat{g}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}\,d\xi$ is well-defined. Question is: Is there any relation between $g$ and $\tilde{g}$?

Comment: $\tilde{g}= (e^{i\pi \xi^2})^{\vee} \ast g$

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many relations between these two functions, but possibly the most interesting one is the fact that this function will represent a fixed-time evolution of the original function according to the solution of the Schrödinger's IVP

$$ \begin{cases} \partial _t u =  i \Delta  u \\ u_0 = g \end{cases}$$

(This can be seen by observing that for fixed time $t$ we've that $\hat{u} (\xi,t) = e^{-4i\pi^2 \xi^2 t} \hat{g} (\xi) $)

For example, it can be shown that we may write

$$ \tilde{g} (x) = (-i)^{1/2} e^{-4 \pi i  x^2} * g (x) $$

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. Can u explain what is $n$ in the last expression. Also can you prove this last expression, or provide me some good reference where I can find the missing details.

Comment: Of course :) This $n$ was misplaced, I apologize for that. I was thinking of the $n$-dimensional version of this equation, but with 1 this works for our case. 

For the details, you may look at Linares and Ponce's book 'Introduction to  Nonlinear Dispersive Equations', Chapters 1 (for the proof of the fact that the transform of $e^{itx²}$ is also of this form) and 4 (for the general Theory of Linear Schrödinger's Equation)

Comment: Thanks again :) Btw I am working on this question: For $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, prove or disprove: $\hat{f}(\xi)+e^{i\pi \xi^2}\hat{g}(\xi) = 0$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ implies $\hat{f} = \hat{g} = 0$. If u can provide some suggestion would be helpful, otherwise I got the hint that everything i need is there in that book.

Comment: Well, using the remarks I just said, you can, for example, take $g$ to be any  Schwartz function, and $f$ to be implicitly defined by $\hat{f} = - e^{i\pi \xi²} \hat{g} (\xi)$. Then it is straighforward that $f$ itself is a Schwartz function, and nonzero. That is, just take $f$ to be a fixed-time stage of the solution to the Schrödinger equation.